# Form - Show partial form in block then populate full form with partial data

Tags: entities, blocks

I have a content type with various fields.
Now i would like to show a couple of it's fields in a block globally and on submission post that data to the full form page and pre-populate the already provided fields.

Can this be done easily with the drupal core or is there a helpful module you guys can recommend?

Answer (score 0):

As contrib is an extension of core there are always ways to do stuff in core that you can do with contrib, it's just often contrib makes it easier, quicker, and more easily maintainable at the sacrifice of more code.

For this I would look at the prepopulate module which allows fields in most forms to be pre-populated from the $_REQUEST variable:

https://drupal.org/project/prepopulate

If you want to use just core then you know what you're outputting in the block, at a guess you could form_alter the form linked to prepopulate.

Comment: thank, this is half of what i need. now i need to know how to render a partial form within a block or .tpl.php